# Solr indexing is taking way too long

Tags: solr, indexing

We need to create our index in Solr and it is taking way too long.  We have about 800k records and it seems like it is going to take 15 to 20 days at the rate at which it is indexing.  We are looking for a one time index for now.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using DIH, post your data import config.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a system to index about 300,000 records and after some performance tests, I configured SOLR to commit every 5 minutes. Look at the solrconfig.xml. There are several directives related to committing changes but you should not be committing after each record update. Either commit after every 100-200 records or commit every 5 minutes. This is especially important during a reindex of all data.

I chose 5 minutes because it is a reasonable setting for ongoing sync as well, since we poll our db for changes every minute. We tell users that it takes 5 minutes or so for changes to flow through to SOLR, and so far everyone is happy with that.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience indexing big chunks of data might take a while. Index I'm working on have 2m items (size: 10G). Full index takes about 40 hours using DB.

There are some factors that might slowing you down:

- Memory. One think is having memory on the box, and the other is to allow Solr to use it. Give Solr as much as you can afford for indexing time (you can easily change that later)
- Garbage collector. With default one we had a lot of problems (after 20-30h indexing was interrupted and we had to start from the beginning)
- Make Solr cache results from DB
- Check all queries, how expensive they are
- Index in smaller batches. If I would index 300k items it would take much longer, than indexing them in 3 batches of 100k
- Having lots of big full text stored fields is not helping (if you don't need to store something, don't do that)

Comment: Can you give the sample of configurations for each suggestions you have made?

Comment: I don't really work on that project anymore since it was years ago. 1. It's hardware spec of the box, maybe also some Java prams.  2. Can't remember exact Java setting 3. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#CachedSqlEntityProcessor 4. Well that's SQL, run explain and analyze the outcome. 5. You can try to use https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Accessing_request_parameters to limit the number of records involved in each batch. 6. Think twice about your schema, just minimize it. Try to remove some and see if it has any effect on the speed.

Comment: Just in case if it may be useful to others. I have increased the batch size from -1 to 50 and speed increased by 4X. Then I allotted more RAM to solr instance by using -m 30g flag speed again increased by 2X

Comment: Great! Yeah, Solr/Lucene loves memory! I think that with smaller batches index is updated more often and that helps lots. It's a nice game to find a good spot of batch size

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why the indexing takes so much time ? any preprocessing steps taking time ? cause this seem to be taking a usually high time.
Are these database records or rich documents ?
How are you indexing the data ? are you running frequent commits or optimization ?
Hows the system memory, cpu, space behaving ?
Might want to revisit some settings in [solrconfig.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#mainIndex_Section)

If all of the above seems fine, you can try an option -
Create seperate cores and run parallel jobs to index the data. After the index completes you can either merge the index or use [distributed search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch).

Comment: No preprocessing steps.  These are database records.  Indexing them through the Drupal administration console.  There is nothing else going on on the server as it is not in production yet.  This is a quad core machine with 4 GB  memory and 200Gb HD.  Also it is Apache Solr using schema.xml version: drupal-1.4